# Разные маршруты с помощью express Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Я совсем новичок в Node.js.  У меня есть несколько однотипных маршрутизаций для каждой table1, table2, table3

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
router.get("/table1", (req, res, next) => {
    res.send('Table1');
});

router.get("/table2", (req, res, next) => {
    res.send('Table2');
});

router.get("/table3", (req, res, next) => {
    res.send('Table3');
});
```

Например, когда я хочу добавить table4, table5, и т д, то мне все время приходится добавлять соответсвующий router.get для этой table. И это не совсем правильно. Хотелось бы понять, можно ли как то написать один router.get, чтобы не нужно было каждый раз под новую таблицу добавлять новый соответствующий router.get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно сделать это следующим образом:

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

// с помощью регулярки ищем цифру
router.get("/table(\\d+)", (req, res, next) => { 
    const num = req.params[0]; // из объекта достаем цифру
    res.send(`Table${num}`); // отправляем, используя интерполяцию
});
```

Comment: а вот если названия таблиц (у нас это table1, table2, table3) не такие однотипные, а вообще разные слова, что в этому случае предпринять?

Comment: @KK_1999 насколько разные? Всегда можно найти какой-то шаблон и создать роут. Если, конечно, таблицы не названы, например, '123table' 'sometableqwerty'. Гораздо удобнее создать роут типа /table/:tableName и вытаскивать имя таблицы

Comment: @KK_1999 https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html вот статья про роуты

Comment: просто вдруг эти названия таблиц это будут какие-то разные слова, например: workers,  responsibilities, units, ... и вот как тут взять один шаблон я не совсем понимаю

Comment: @KK_1999 тогда лучший подход использовать такой роут: /tables/:tableName. Где tableName - любое название таблицы